# Two values being compared before function returns the value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some code where a function (which contains a promise) runs and then returns a boolean value. I then check to see if that value is true, and if so run some other code. I had the values logging to the console to do some debugging, and I noticed that the if statement that checks to see if the function returned true was running before the function even returned anything.

I have attempted to use "await" and "async" but I haven't found any success in using them.

```
javascript
function myFunc()
   promise()
      .then(value => {
         console.log('Returned true');
         return true;
      })
      .catch(err => {
         console.log('Error', err);
      });
end

if (myFunc()) {
   console.log('Value was true');
} else {
   console.log('Value was false');
}
```

Expected:

```
Returned true
Value was true
```

Actual:

```
Value was false
Returned true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to return a promise from inside your function, in the moment you use promises you are working with async code. That means that in order to get the value from the promise, the promise needs to be fulfilled first.

In your case you are evaluating the return value of your function, not the returned value of the promise. Since you do not have an explicit return in your function, it is returning undefined. That is why you see `value was false` in the console. Then your promise gets fulfilled and you see `Returned true` in the console, but you never evaluated that value return by the promise.

Supposing that you are invoking your function from the global scope you will need to use .then syntax to get access to the value returned by your promise.

So if your function is something like this:

```
function myFunc() {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(value => {
      console.log('Returned true');
      return true;
    })
 }
```

Your if statement should turn into something like this:

```
myFunc().then(value => {
   if(value) console.log('It is true')
   else console.log('Is it false')
 })
```

Basically you wait for your promise to be fulfilled and when that happens you get the return value by param (in this simple example it is always true but it could be false as well).

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning the promise from the function:

```
function myFunc()
   return promise()
      .then(value => {
         console.log('Returned true');
         return true;
      })
      .catch(err => {
         console.log('Error', err);
      });
end

if (myFunc()) {
   console.log('Value was true');
} else {
   console.log('Value was false');
}
```

This is not the best practice, I would stick with a good old promise chain:

```
promise()
  .then(value => {
     if (value) {
       console.log('Value was true');
     } else {
       console.log('Value was false');
     }
   })
   .catch(err => {
         console.log('Error', err);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "await" to wait the promise response

```
promise = () => new Promise( (resolve, reject ) => resolve(true) );

async function myFunc(){
   try {
     let value = await promise();

     if (value === true){
       console.log('Returned true');
       return true;
     }
   } catch (err) {
     console.log('Error', err);
   }
}

async function main(){

  if ( await myFunc() ) {
   console.log('Value was true');
  } else {
   console.log('Value was false');
  }
}

main();
```